# Aggregate column in one column (or add new line) in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

In my query in SQL Server (T-SQL), I want 2 columns as result: `eventsID` and `T_E_Discriminatorio_ID`.

This is my query:

```
select 
    e.id eventsID,
    case 
       when DisabilityID is not null 
          then (select T_E_Discriminatorio_ID 
                from t_e_discriminatorio ted, Disability d 
                where ted.Dettaglio_T_E_Discriminatorio = d.Name
                  and DisabilityID = d.Id)
    end T_E_Discriminatorio_ID,
    case 
       when EthnicityId is not null 
          then (select T_E_Discriminatorio_ID 
                from t_e_discriminatorio ted, Ethnicity e 
                where ted.Dettaglio_T_E_Discriminatorio = e.Name
                  and EthnicityId = e.Id)
    end T_E_Discriminatorio_ID
from
    events e 
inner join 
    DiscriminatoryAct d on e.id = d.EventId;
```

The result is:

```
eventsID T_E_Discriminatorio_ID T_E_Discriminatorio_ID
62            8                        NULL
63            8                        7    
64            NULL                     7        
65            7                        6
```

I want aggregate T_E_Discriminatorio_ID for to have:

```
62 8
63 8
63 7
64 7
65 7
65 6
```

insert a new line with same events_id when there are 2 T_E_Discriminatorio_ID.

the schema are this:

```
t_e_discriminatorio:
T_E_Discriminatorio_ID 
T_E_Discriminatorio 
Dettaglio_T_E_Discriminatorio <---> fk to Name on table (Disability or Ethnicity or Gender or Religion or SexualOrientation) table 

DiscriminatoryAct:
Id
CrimeId
EventId   <---> fk to id on events table
Note
OSCECategoryId
DiscriminatoryArea
DisabilityId  <---> fk to id on Disability table
EthnicityId <---> fk to id on Ethnicity table
GenderId <---> fk to id on Gender table
ReligionId <---> fk to id on Religion table
SexualOrientationId <---> fk to id on SexualOrientation table

Disability (like Ethnicity or Gender or Religion or SexualOrientation)
Id <--> fk to DisabilityId on DiscriminatoryAct
Name <--> fk to Dettaglio_T_E_Discriminatorio on t_e_discriminatorio
```

How can I do that?

thanks
regards

Comment: Have you considered just `left join`ing

Comment: how? you can write query pls?

Comment: Evolve - no one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) anymore. In addition, use best practices to help others understand your schema (which you did not post). Reference EVERY column with the appropriate alias so we don't have to guess which table it comes from. Cryptic single letter aliases are not very useful either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a UNION which combines the 2 case statements together. Based on the schema you showed us, the following should give you the required result:

```
select * from (
select
    disc_a.event_ID as Event_ID,
    ev.T_E_Discriminatorio_ID as T_E_Discriminatorio_ID 
from DiscriminatoryAct disc_a
inner join Disability d on disc_a.DisabilityId = d.ID
inner join Events ev on ev.event_ID = disc_a.event_ID

UNION

select
    disc_a.event_ID as Event_ID,
    ev.T_E_Discriminatorio_ID as T_E_Discriminatorio_ID 
from DiscriminatoryAct disc_a
inner join Ethnicity e on disc_a.EthnicityId = e.Id
inner join Events ev on ev.event_ID = disc_a.event_ID
) a
order by a.Event_ID
```

Comment: T-SQL doesn't support `Case` (`Switch`) statements, only `CASE` expressions, and a `UNION` doesn't "combine" case statements (or expressions) it turns multiple datasets which have the same definition into a single one. Also, if this above if the above returns unique values in each data set, then this will be better off with a `UNION ALL`, rather than a costly `UNION`.

Comment: You are right, what I meant to say is that the OPs case statement can easily be transferred to the query I posted in my answer. You are right also regarding the difference between UNION and UNION ALL. For the OP's reference, you can check the difference between a UNION and a UNION ALL here: https://dataschool.com/learn-sql/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all/#:~:text=UNION%20ALL%20keeps%20all%20of,returning%20the%20combined%20data%20set.